# Get json data stored as text from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

First I have html - bootstrap tab:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Opsti podaci</a></li>
  <li><a id="mapa1" href="#mapa" data-toggle="tab">Mapa parcele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#dokumenti" data-toggle="tab">Dokumenti</a></li>
  <li><a href="#komentari" data-toggle="tab">Komentari</a></li>
</ul>
```

and below:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="mapa">
        <div id="myMap" style="height:500px;"></div>


     </div>
```

In database I have this:
[image]

Now I write this jquery/ajax code to get json stored as text from mySql database:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('a#mapa1').click(function (e) {

 $.ajax({
            url: "getMap.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true, 
            data: { ajdi:ajdi}, //your form data to post goes here as a json object
            dataType: "html",

            success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
                BlitzMap.setMap( 'myMap', true, 'data' ); 
                BlitzMap.init();   
            },  
            error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            }
        });
        });
```

but when I click on a#mapa1 notning happend... also when I manualy add this code to execude in console i get error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

What can be a problem here? I dont see! Please help! Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

```
 try {

     $result = $db->prepare("SELECT json FROM map WHERE id_parcele=:ajdi AND user_id=:user_id");
     $result->execute(array(':ajdi' => $_POST['ajdi'], ':user_id' => $user_id));
     $result = $result->fetchAll(); 

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo $result;
}
```

this produce me just `Array` when I chenge echo $result to echo json_encode($result) again dont work... how to get just plain text ?

With print_r I get this code:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [json] => {"zoom":7,"tilt":0,"mapTypeId":"hybrid","center":{"lat":20.487486793750797,"lng":74.22363281640626},"overlays":[{"type":"polygon","title":"","content":"","fillColor":"#000000","fillOpacity":0.3,"strokeColor":"#000000","strokeOpacity":0.9,"strokeWeight":3,"paths":[[{"lat":"21.329035778926478","lng":"73.46008301171878"},{"lat":"21.40065516914794","lng":"78.30505371484378"},{"lat":"20.106233605369603","lng":"77.37121582421878"},{"lat":"20.14749530904506","lng":"72.65808105859378"}]]}]}
            [0] => {"zoom":7,"tilt":0,"mapTypeId":"hybrid","center":{"lat":20.487486793750797,"lng":74.22363281640626},"overlays":[{"type":"polygon","title":"","content":"","fillColor":"#000000","fillOpacity":0.3,"strokeColor":"#000000","strokeOpacity":0.9,"strokeWeight":3,"paths":[[{"lat":"21.329035778926478","lng":"73.46008301171878"},{"lat":"21.40065516914794","lng":"78.30505371484378"},{"lat":"20.106233605369603","lng":"77.37121582421878"},{"lat":"20.14749530904506","lng":"72.65808105859378"}]]}]}
        )

)
```

but I need to get just this:

```
{"zoom":13,"tilt":0,"mapTypeId":"hybrid","center":{"lat":45.38591280296377,"lng":19.93632316979983},"overlays":[{"type":"polygon","title":"Polje 1","content":"Vojvodina","fillColor":"#ffbf1a","fillOpacity":0.3,"strokeColor":"#000","strokeOpacity":0.8,"strokeWeight":3,"paths":[[{"lat":"45.37867863632308","lng":"19.948768615722656"},{"lat":"45.370719925928746","lng":"19.941558837890625"},{"lat":"45.36227764550136","lng":"19.92816925048828"},{"lat":"45.359262240003495","lng":"19.942245483398438"},{"lat":"45.35588479505299","lng":"19.955806732177734"},{"lat":"45.35974471568275","lng":"19.958553314208984"},{"lat":"45.36312193024184","lng":"19.959583282470703"},{"lat":"45.365534102931655","lng":"19.960613250732422"},{"lat":"45.36529289029106","lng":"19.96490478515625"},{"lat":"45.37084052080666","lng":"19.970226287841797"}]]}]}
```

How I can do that?

Comment: You're missing a }); at the end of your javascript.  Typo or in original?

Comment: Thanks, that was error, but also my php file is wrong

Comment: I update question with my php file ...

Comment: Change you echo $result to a print_r($result).  If that doesn't give you what you want, you'll need to do additional processing in your PHP

Comment: You never check if your query actually returns rows.

Comment: I update question with result for function print_r... How to get my text without Array ... ... so just plain text like on my database ?

Comment: echo $result[0][0] should get that result, but you may want to set up a a loop to loop through that array instead.

Comment: yes that was right answer but why I cant use DATA now like this: success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
                BlitzMap.setMap( 'myMap', true, 'data' ); 
                BlitzMap.init();   
            },

Comment: so BlitzMap.setMap( 'myMap', true, 'data' ); data was not used as well ... I try manyaly to add and work ok...

Comment: dont you should for your php do: `return json_encode($result);`